# Deceleration to stopping point, with snapshot times/speeds

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, projectile-motion

Simple question but I've confused myself over-complicating it.

- Say initial speed is 72ms
- distance is 0 (increasing)
- deceleration rate fixed at -2.2mss

How far and what time will it take to stop?

The tricky part then is I need to calculate the snapshot time and speed when it hits various milestone distances (area under Vt-graph) such as 900m, 600m, 300m, **TO GO** until the end of the stopping distance.

ie, total stopping distance of 1200m, then:

- at 900m from the end stopping point (zero speed) what is the current time/speed.
- at 300m from the end stopping point, what is the current time/speed.

**EDIT**

In the diagram, after covering 500metres (A+B) what is the current speed and time at this point.

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A)$  use $v_f=v_i +at$ to find when the final velocity equals zero.

$B)$ When you have the time, use $0=(v_i)^2 +2ad$ to solve for the distance, d the car will travel before stopping.

Then when you have total distance, subtract the distance you want such as $900$ to plug in equation $(v_f)^2=(v_i)^2 +2ad$.

Comment: Sorry, don't quite get you. A) makes sense, giving me 1178m and B) gives me 32s. I'm happy with those. What I can't work out is the next part of my question which is working out what the "snapshot" speed is when the decelerating object passes 900m, 600m, 300m,(TO GO) etc

Comment: ie, while the object is decelerating, it is covering distance. When it passes X distance (say Total Distance-900) what is the time and speed at that point

Comment: It takes $32.73$ seconds for the cart to stop and it covers $1178.18$ meters before stopping. Now you want to find the speed and time when the cart is at position $1177.18-900=278.18$ This gives our distance $d$.  We use $d=v_i+at)$ to solve for time. Which is $278.18=72-2.2t$ which gives $t=4.12$ in our interval

Comment: now plug time into $v_f=v_i +at$ to find speed. $v_f=72-(2.2)(4.12)$ which gives about $62.936$.

Comment: Same case for the other question

Comment: Ah I see... diagram added for clarity

Comment: Sorry, 278=72-2.2t - t=4.12. How did you get that?

Comment: my bad, $278=72t-(0.5)(2.2)t^2$ which gives $t=4.12$ if you use the quadratic formula. This is because $d=v_i t+0.5at^2$

Comment: $v_f=v_i+at$ now gives you the speed at that time

Comment: Ok, great, that works nicely, thank you. Would you mind explaining how you got **vf=vi+at** into **d=at^2+bt+c** ? multiply through by t?

Comment: $d=v_i t+0.5at^2$ is a standard kinematic equation you need to know (its part of the 5 kinematic equations). It is derived from $v_f=v_i+at$ by adding $v_i$ to both sides and collect the terms and then multiply both sides by $0.5t$. This website probably explains it better than me:https://www.carolina.com/teacher-resources/Interactive/derivation-of-the-kinematics-equation/tr32615.tr

Comment: I got the time from the standard equation $d=v_i t+0.5at^2$ and then plugged it into $v_f=v_i+at$